# Consulta SQL conteo par o impar

Tags: sql

Tengo conocimientos para consultas SQL básicas. Sin embargo, para la app que estoy desarrollando necesito resolver la siguiente cuestión. Tengo una tabla registros(id, fecha, hora).

Ejemplos:

```
(1,2020/01/17,08:00)
(2,2020/01/17,14:00)
(3,2020/01/18,07:55)
(4,2020/01/18,11:00)
(5,2020/01/18,14:00)
```

El día 2020/01/17 aparece en un número par de registros(2). El día 2020/01/18 aparece en un número impar de registros(3). Necesitaría saber si cada fecha aparece en un número par o impar de registros, ya que cada día tendrá posteriormente un tratamiento diferente según aparezca en un nº par o impar.
Gracias.

Comment: Saber si un número es par o impar es un problema básico de programación ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Cuál manejador de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que intentaste? que problema tuviste con lo que intentaste?

Comment: Qué has intentado? Suena como que quieres que lo hagamos por ti. Así no funciona este sitio

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada necesitas la definición de "Par" (o de Paridad) esta es (de publico conocimiento) divisible entre 2 SIN RESTO, el resto de la división (o "Modulo") es una operación comúnmente asociada a "%" ([por ej en SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql)), o hecha por alguna función([por ejemplo en MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod))

Teniendo la definicion (digase "Modulo = 0") lo que resta es contar los registros, para esto la funcion agregada [Count()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql) (Prácticamente universal), "colapsará" todos los registros (entregando en este caso la cantidad de ellos) según los cortes especificados en la seccion de "GROUP BY" de la consulta, en este caso queremos "Cantidad de registros POR FECHA", y por tanto ése será nuestros valores de corte.

Con los conceptos en mano traigamos un ejemplo realista, basado en tus datos, en un entorno de SQL Server; teniendo el siguiente esquema:

```
CREATE TABLE Registros
(Id     INT, 
 Fecha  DATE, 
 Hora  TIME, 
);
GO
INSERT INTO Registros(Id, Fecha, Hora)
VALUES
(1,'2020/01/17','08:00'),
(2,'2020/01/17','14:00'),
(3,'2020/01/18','07:55'),
(4,'2020/01/18','11:00'),
(5,'2020/01/18','14:00')
;
GO
```

Podremos realizar [la siguiente consulta](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a6ee/4/0):

```
SELECT Fecha,
   Modulo = Count(*) % 2
FROM Registros
GROUP BY Fecha
```

Notese que "Modulo = " solo asigna un alias a la columna (lo hago así porque el alias al final es mas difícil de leer), ésto devolverá:

[image: | Fecha | Modulo | | ---------- | ------ | | 2020-01-17 | 0 | | 2020-01-18 | 1 |]
Podríamos darle un "formato" a la columna 'Modulo' con [CASE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql), de la siguiente forma:

```
...
   Modulo = CASE WHEN Count(*) % 2 = 0 THEN 'Par' ELSE 'Impar' END
...
```

Retornando entonces:
[image: | Fecha | Modulo | | ---------- | ------ | | 2020-01-17 | Par | | 2020-01-18 | Impar |]
También podríamos evitar el colapso de los registros utilizando [la "versión analítica" de la funcion COUNT()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#i-using-count-with-over) gracias a [la clausula OVER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) convirtiendo la función en una "función agregada en ventana", que consiste sencillamente en un "post-procesado" del resultado de la consulta, un ejemplo "manual" del comportamiento sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT Id,
      Registros.Fecha, 
      Hora,
      Paridad
FROM Registros
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Fecha,
      Paridad = CASE WHEN Count(*) % 2 = 0 THEN 'Par' ELSE 'Impar' END
   FROM Registros
   GROUP BY Fecha
) Conteo_Fechas
ON Conteo_Fechas.Fecha = Registros.Fecha
```

Tendrá el retorno idéntico a:

```
SELECT Id,
   Fecha,
   Hora,
   Paridad = CASE WHEN Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Fecha) % 2 = 0 THEN 'Par' ELSE 'Impar' END
FROM Registros
```

Que será:
[image: | Id | Fecha | Hora | Paridad | | -- | ---------- | ----- | ------- | | 1 | 2020-01-17 | 08:00 | Par | | 2 | 2020-01-17 | 14:00 | Par | | 3 | 2020-01-18 | 07:55 | Impar | | 4 | 2020-01-18 | 11:00 | Impar | | 5 | 2020-01-18 | 14:00 | Impar |]